# How to set up node.js process.env variables for production with an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

I have searched and searched for a straight forward answer to this question but I have found nothing. I have my local .env file and am successfully loading it with dotenv.

The only answer I can find for setting up the process.env variables for production is to use Elastic Beanstalk.

Is there a way to set these variables up with just an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu based (Linux) EC2 Instances

1. Edit **~/.bashrc** file of User which will run the program

   sudo nano ~/.bashrc
2. Add following line at the end, use any variable_name. Assuming unique and unused

   export API_KEY=btgj32fkf
3. Save File and

   source ~/.bashrc

Now, in node program process.env.API_KEY will be available.

For different operating System of EC2, method above will slightly change

Comment: doesn't work. process.env.--whatever, doesn't get read in node with this method

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal server. you can always set env by

```
EXPORT FOO=bar
```

Comment: As soon as the server restarts, wouldn't the variables reset?

Comment: put it to login shell rc so that it get source on startup?

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ ! -d "$MyVar" ]]; then 
    export MyVar="abc"
    echo 'export MyVar="abc"' >> ~/.bashrc
fi
```

use this code. it saves MyVar in ~/.bashrc permanently